# Javascript for scrolling to a div IDs on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a total novice when it comes to javascript hence I am seeking your help.

My markup is like this:

```
<body >

<div class="header_link">

<h1 style="clear:both; padding:5px;">Smooth Scroll by Dezinerfolio</h1>

<a name="top" href="#footer">GO TO FOOTER</a>
<a href="#middle">GO TO MIDDLE</a>

  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec diam  magna, consequat non, adipiscing quis, congue a, mauris. Duis convallis  leo quis metus. </p>
</div>


<div class="middle_link">

<a name="middle" href="#top">GO TO TOP</a>
<a href="#footer">GO TO FOOTER</a>

  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec diam  magna, consequat non, adipiscing quis, congue a, mauris. Duis convallis  leo quis metus. </p>
</div>

<div class="footer_link">

<a name="footer" href="#top">GO TO HEADER</a>
<a href="#middle">GO TO MIDDLE</a>

  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec diam  magna, consequat non, adipiscing quis, congue a, mauris. Duis convallis  leo quis metus. </p>
</div>

</body>
```

What I want is when a visitor clicks on that perticular button, the page should **smoothly / slowly scroll** to that perticular `div`.

*I know there are a lot of plugins in jQuery and MooTools but I do not want to use them because this is the only javascript function requred in my site and rest is all plain CSS activity. Hence there is no point loading a whole 60 to 100 KB of JavaScript library (jQuery or MooTools) to achieve this small function. **I am looking for a simple plain JavaScript function***

Kindly help!

Comment: you can also use a `<a name` tags

Comment: So do you want jQuery? (just jQuery)

Comment: @Derek As mentioned above.....I know there are a lot of plugins in jQuery and MooTools but I do not want to use them because this is the only javascript function requred in my site and rest is all plain CSS activity. Hence there is no point loading a whole 60 to 100 KB library to achieve this small function.

Comment: @Vikram - jQuery: 32KB, you can from the [development version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js), just delete all those useless functions, and just left with the ones you are using. That would trim it a lot smaller.

Comment: @Derek again as mentioned above I am a novice when it comes to JavaScript. I dont even know how to read JavaScript code. That is my main challenge.

Comment: Vikram if you cant read javascript code, please dont ask questions about it.
Its a question/answer website , not a `give me the code` website.

Also, if you cant read js, you should use inbuilt jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just look at the jQuery source and see how they do it.

Alternatively, Google told me about these pages, which look promising:

- http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript
- http://www.dezinerfolio.com/2007/08/08/df-javascript-smooth-scroll

Answer (score 0):

*"I am looking for a simple plain JavaScript function"*

There is no simple plain Javascript solution to this problem. Javascript does provide a "scrollTo" function, but it it will scroll instantly, not smoothly or slowly.

If you need to support a wide range of browsers, you should use jQuery for this. Animations like this are what jQuery is for, and a lot of people have put a whole bunch of effort into making sure this feature of jQuery is easy to use and that it performs well. Replicating this functionality yourself is not a good use of your time.

You *can* do this easily with CSS3 transitions, but these are not supported in IE (yet). If you don't care about IE, this is an excellent solution as well.

Comment: You can't do scrolling with transistions, as far as I know. But apart from that I agree - this is library stuff